HTTP 404 response from KeycloakBuilder java
I am trying to execute this code:
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
        //http://localhost:8080/realms/API/protocol/openid-connect/token
                //.serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/realms/API/protocol/openid-connect/token")
                .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/realms/API/protocol/openid-connect/auth")
                .realm("API")
                .username("xxxxxxxx")
                .password("xxxxxxxx")
                .grantType("password") // or OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS
                .clientId("APIUSERS")
                .clientSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(20).build())
                .build();
AccessTokenResponse tokenResponse = keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken();
System.out.println("Access Token: " + tokenResponse.getToken());

This is the error I am getting

Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found

curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/realms/API/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=APIUSERS' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'username=xxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'password=xxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'

But my keycloak server is working fine and I am able to get a response with the  above curl command
So what is the exact serverUrl to use for KeycloakBuilder?

Just use "serverUrl("http://localhost:8080")
see the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79148537/keycloak-java-service-account-create-user/79150874#79150874

Thanks @Bench Vue. Its working (serverUrl("localhost:8080")
